# redux form validation is not being received

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to disable the submit button for my form. I've removed most of the handlers and inputs accept for the 'name' input, so it's clearer to see. The name input works fine, however when I add a validation prop to the name input, and disabled prop to the submit button, the button still stays active. What am I missing?

```
    export class RecipeForm extends React.Component {

      onChange = e => {
        const { value, name } = e.target;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      };

      // **** other function handlers here *****//


      required = value => {
        if (!value || value === '') {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
        return undefined;
      }

      render() {

        const { name } = this.state;
        const { submitSucceeded, handleSubmit, valid } = this.props;

        if (submitSucceeded) {  // submitSucceeded is a prop of redux form, boolean: true, and succeed to submit 
          alert("You have successfully added a new recipe")
          return <Redirect to='/your-menu' />
        }

        let newCategory;
        if (otherCheckbox) {
          newCategory = <NewCategory addNewCategory={this.addNewCategory} />;
        }



        return (
          <div className="form">
            <Alerts />

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(recipe => this.onSubmit(recipe))}>
              <h2>Add a new favorite recipe!</h2>

              <label htmlFor="name"> Recipe Name </label>
              <input
                name="name"
                id="name"
                type="text"
                label="Recipe Name"
                value={name}
                validate={[this.required]}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />


              // **** other inputs here ***** ///
              

              <button type="submit"
                disabled={!this.props.valid}
              >Submit</button>
            </form>

            <br></br>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      menuItems: state.menu.menuItems,
      categoryList: state.users.categoryList,
      userId: state.auth.id,
      authToken: state.auth.authToken
    });

    RecipeForm = connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipeForm);

    export default reduxForm({
      form: "recipe",
      onSubmitFail: (errors, dispatch) =>
        dispatch(focus("recipe", Object.keys(errors)[0]))
    })(RecipeForm);
```

Comment: When you ```console.log``` props, what is the value of the ```valid``` property?

Comment: a boolean value, it says true.

Comment: So it says that the value is valid, hence the ```!this.props.valid``` returns ```false``` and the button is not disabled.

Comment: Possibly you want to check if the field is also dirty perhaps. If it is dirty and not valid, disable it. It it's not dirty also disable it.

Comment: to be more clear, it says "true" for !this.props.valid and it also says "true" for this.props.valid. so somethings not getting listened to